# Finding the pdf of $Y=X^2-X$ given that the pdf of $X$ is $f_X(x) = 3x^2I_{(0,1)}(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Consider a random variable $X$ having pdf
>
> $$f_X(x) = 3x^2I_{(0,1)}(x)$$
>
> Give the pdf of $Y=X^2−X$ and the value of $E(Y)$.

I have from an inverse calculator that if $Y=X^2−X$ then $X = {1\over2}(1\pm \sqrt{4Y+1})$. We have,

$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)$

$=P(X^2-X\leq y)$

$=P(X\leq{1\over2}(1\pm \sqrt{4Y+1}))$

$=P(({1\over2}(1- \sqrt{4Y+1}) \leq X \leq {1\over2}(1 + \sqrt{4Y+1}))$.

$=F_X({1\over2}(1 + \sqrt{4Y+1}))$ $-$ $F_X({1\over2}(1- \sqrt{4Y+1})$

$=\frac{1}{8}\left(\sqrt{4y+1}-1\right)^3+\frac{1}{8}\left(\sqrt{4y+1}+1\right)^3$

I do not think I am doing this correctly. Based on other similar problems that I am looking at, this was much more tedious in comparison, and so I think I might have made an error. I am new to these kind of problems, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Very first steps: (1) Find the support of $Y.$ (2) Notice that the transformation is not 1-1.

Comment: Major mistake: The assertion that $P(X^2-X\leq y)=P(X\leq{1\over2}(1\pm \sqrt{4y+1}))$ is not true since $\{X^2-X\leq y\}\ne\{X\leq{1\over2}(1\pm \sqrt{4y+1})\}$. Actually the very meaning of an inequality like $X\leq{1\over2}(1\pm \sqrt{4y+1})$ (with $\pm$) should be explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch the graph $Y=X^2-X$, one can see that
$$0 \ge Y \ge -\frac{1}{4}$$
and there are two values of $X$ corresponding to each $Y$, except for $Y=-\frac{1}{4}$.

By transformation method formula

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(x_1)\bigg|\frac{dx_1}{dy}\bigg|+f_X(x_2)\bigg|\frac{dx_2}{dy}\bigg|$$
$$=\frac{3}{8}(1-\sqrt{4y+1})^2\bigg|\frac{d}{dy}(1-\sqrt{4y+1})\bigg|+\frac{3}{8}(1+\sqrt{4y+1})^2\bigg|\frac{d}{dy}(1+\sqrt{4y+1})\bigg|$$
$$=\frac{3}{8}(2+4y-2\sqrt{4y+1})\frac{2}{\sqrt{4y+1}}+\frac{3}{8}(2+4y+2\sqrt{4y+1})\frac{2}{\sqrt{4y+1}}$$
$$=3\frac{1+2y}{\sqrt{1+4y}}$$

Comment: Do you mean for this to be the PDF $f_Y(y)?$ And for what values of $y$?

Comment: @BruceET Yes. Isn't that the OP is looking for?

Comment: Better now that you've fixed the notation.(+1)

Comment: And $E(Y)$ would be $\int_{-1/4}^0$$Y$$3(1+2y)\over{(\sqrt{1+4y})}$?

Comment: @JohnH Yes.....

Comment: @JohnH E(Y)=-0.15 by wolfram alpha.

Comment: I graphed $X^2-X$. What about the graph lets you know that Y takes on those values?

Comment: @JohnH I copied from your result.

Comment: Oh, never mind, it's because we're looking at values of X from 0 to 1.